# Why did John switch to the unwired truck?

Tags: plot-explanation, snitch

In the movie "Snitch" (2013) when making the delivery to Mexico, what was the point of John Matthews (The Rock) secretly switching from a wired/surveilled truck to his 2nd truck that was not wired?

What difference did it make using an unwired truck? All events could have taken place using a wired truck.

> John agrees to deliver a pile of cash from USA to Mexico, but he's rightfully worried he'll be bumped off after the delivery is made, so he wants the interception to take place before crossing the border. >!Beforehand, he parks his 2nd truck at a rendezvous point. Soon after the start of the journey he switches trucks, so the trip will take place using an unwired truck. During the trip, his sidekick extracts the mobile phone number of the kingpin from an associate, which John then forwards on to the DEA, who track and arrest the kingpin. Actually it would have been easier to convey the phone number by just speaking hands free instead of dialling. The truck is indeed intercepted before the border, but by the cartel rather than the DEA, because the cartel discover that John is linked to the DEA via his son's felony prosecution for drug trafficking, an eventuality that John did not anticipate and thus could not have influenced his plan to shift the endgame from Mexico to USA.

Answer (score 1):

Because he didn't want the federal authorities to know what his plan was.

It was something about making sure the cash handover took place on US soil as it was almost certain that he'd be murdered in Mexico.

Unfortunately, we don't learn what the plan in detail was because it all falls apart when the cartel learns that John is an informant.

Comment: The handover was never going to take place on US soil, only the DEA interception. But anyway, how does switching trucks help move the capture event from Mexico to USA, or even conceal his plan to do this?

Comment: We don't know because it's never explained. John apparently planned on moving the handover to the US but we're never told how.